# nginx and phpmyadmin 404

Tags: nginx

i was creating a seperate Configuration for phpmyadmin on my raspberry pi 2. The Webserver is using nginx.

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name 192.168.178.26;

       location /pma/ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    allow 192.168.178.28;
    deny  all;
}

location ~ ^/pma/(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/phpfpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;

    # From fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      /usr/share/phpmyadmin; # <-- Changed
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
 }
}
```

So this is my Configuration and when im going for 192.168.178.28/pma/ im getting only a 404 Page. I added the allow and deny because i want that phpmyadmin should only be accessed in the local network. Im hoping somebody could help me please to fix this 404 Error.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are missing an `index index.php;` statement, which will convert your `192.168.178.28/pma/` URI into `192.168.178.28/pma/index.php`.

Your `allow/deny` only applies to non-PHP files because the directives are not inherited by all locations.

You might simplify your configuration by inheriting the `alias`, `allow` and `deny` directives:

```
location ^~ /pma/ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    allow 192.168.178.28;
    deny  all;

    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/phpfpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;

        fastcgi_param  ...
        ...
    }
}
```